# Make the numbers 1-100 using six 6s

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, calculation-puzzle

> Rules: 
>   Make the numbers 1-100 using six 6s 
>   Use the operations + - * / exponentiation and ! 
>   No Rounding as in $((6 - (6 + 6) / 6) + 6!!) / 6 = 9$ 
>   No using other digits 
>   Multi digit numbers and .6 is allowed 
>   Use overhead lines for recurring decimals: $.\overline{6} = .66... = \frac{2}{3}$ 
>   Multifactorial is allowed but each multifactorial can’t have more than 10 factorials: $(6+6)!!!!!!!=12*5=60$ 
>   Subfactorials are allowed: $!n=\lfloor{\frac{n!}{e}+\frac{1}{2}}\rfloor$ 
>   Have Fun!

Comment: Um, isn't 1-100 kinda too much to ask for in one puzzle? 

Comment: Why was this closed? It is clearly focused on 1 problem.

Comment: @eyl327; at school, this would be set as punishment :)

Comment: @JMP It's only punishment if you don't like math. I found this fun and I was able to complete it in a reasonable amount of time (less than 2 hours).

Comment: Yeah why is it closed? There are other puzzles out there that are also 1-100 but they are still open!

Comment: Agreed, and voted to reopen.

Comment: For six digits, that is generous, so I would limit the operations/ characters to the four basic ones, grouping symbols, exponentiation, and the regular factorial.  Consider the use of regular concatenation of digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### All 100 complete!

(Using $6! = 720,\ 6!! = 48$)

> $6+6+6/6-6-6 = 1$
>
>  $6+6/6+6/6-6 = 2$
>
>  $6+6+.6-6-.6 \times 6 = 3$
>
>  $6+6+6 \times .\overline{6}-6-6 = 4$
>
>  $6+6-.6-.6 \times .\overline{6}-6 = 5$
>
>  $6+.6+.6 \times .\overline{6}-6/6 = 6$
>
>  $6+6+.6+.6 \times .\overline{6}-6 = 7$
>
>  $6+6+6-6-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 8$
>
>  $6+6+6/6-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 9$
>
>  $6+6+.\overline{6}-.\overline{6} \times .\overline{6} \times 6 = 10$
>
>  $6+6+6-6-6/6 = 11$
>
>  $6+6+6+6-6-6 = 12$
>
>  $6+6+6+6/6-6 = 13$
>
>  $6+6+6/6+6/6 = 14$
>
>  $6+6+6 \times .\overline{6}-6/6 = 15$
>
>  $6+6+6+6 \times .\overline{6}-6 = 16$
>
>  $6+6+6/6+.\overline{6} \times 6 = 17$
>
>  $6+6 \times 6-6 \times .\overline{6} \times 6 = 18$
>
>  $6+6+.6+.6 \times .\overline{6}+6 = 19$
>
>  $6+6+6+6-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 20$
>
>  $6+6+6-.6+.6 \times 6 = 21$
>
>  $6/6-.6+6 \times .6 \times 6 = 22$
>
>  $6+6+6+6-6/6 = 23$
>
>  $6+6+6+6+6-6 = 24$
>
>  $6+6+6+6+6/6 = 25$
>
>  $6+6 \times 6 \times .\overline{6}-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 26$
>
>  $6 \times 6+.6-6-.6 \times 6 = 27$
>
>  $6+6+6+6+.\overline{6} \times 6 = 28$
>
>  $6+6 \times 6 \times .\overline{6}-6/6 = 29$
>
>  $6+6+6 \times 6 \times .\overline{6}-6 = 30$
>
>  $6+6/6+6 \times .\overline{6} \times 6 = 31$
>
>  $6+6 \times 6-6-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 32$
>
>  $6+6-.6+6 \times .6 \times 6 = 33$
>
>  $6+6 \times 6 \times .\overline{6}+.\overline{6} \times 6 = 34$
>
>  $6+6 \times 6-6-6/6 = 35$
>
>  $6+6+6+6+6+6 = 36$
>
>  $6+6/6+6 \times 6-6 = 37$
>
>  $6/6+6/6+6 \times 6 = 38$
>
>  $6+6 \times 6+.6-.6 \times 6 = 39$
>
>  $6+6 \times 6+6 \times .\overline{6}-6 = 40$
>
>  $6-.6-.6 \times .\overline{6}+6 \times 6 = 41$
>
>  $6+6+6+6 \times .\overline{6} \times 6 = 42$
>
>  $6+.6+.6 \times .\overline{6}+6 \times 6 = 43$
>
>  $6+6+6 \times 6-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 44$
>
>  $6+6 \times 6-.6+.6 \times 6 = 45$
>
>  $66 \times .6+.6 \times .\overline{6}+6 = 46$
>
>  $6+6+6 \times 6-6/6 = 47$
>
>  $6+6+6+6 \times 6-6 = 48$
>
>  $6+6+6/6+6 \times 6 = 49$
>
>  $66-6-6-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 50$
>
>  $66 \times .6+6-.6+6 = 51$
>
>  $6+6+6 \times 6+.\overline{6} \times 6 = 52$
>
>  $66 - 6 - 6 - 6/6 = 53$
>
>  $6 \times 6+6 \times 6 \times .\overline{6}-6 = 54$
>
>  $66+6/6-6-6 = 55$
>
>  $6!!+6!!-6 \times 6-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 56$
>
>  $6 \times 6-.6+6 \times .6 \times 6 = 57$
>
>  $66+6 \times .\overline{6}-6-6 = 58$
>
>  $66-.6-.6 \times .\overline{6}-6 = 59$
>
>  $6+6+6+6+6 \times 6 = 60$
>
>  $66+.6+.6 \times .\overline{6}-6 = 61$
>
>  $66+6-6-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 62$
>
>  $66+6/6-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 63$
>
>  $6 \times 6 \times .\overline{6} \times .\overline{6} \times .\overline{6} \times 6 = 64$
>
>  $66+6-6-6/6 = 65$
>
>  $6+6 \times 6+6 \times .\overline{6} \times 6 = 66$
>
>  $66+6+6/6-6 = 67$
>
>  $6 \times 6+6 \times 6-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 68$
>
>  $66+6+.6-.6 \times 6 = 69$
>
>  $66+6+6 \times .\overline{6}-6 = 70$
>
>  $6 \times 6+6 \times 6-6/6 = 71$
>
>  $6+6 \times 6+6 \times 6-6 = 72$
>
>  $6/6+6 \times 6+6 \times 6 = 73$
>
>  $66+6+6-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 74$
>
>  $66+6-.6+.6 \times 6 = 75$
>
>  $6 \times 6+6 \times 6+.\overline{6} \times 6 = 76$
>
>  $66+6+6-6/6 = 77$
>
>  $66+6+6+6-6 = 78$
>
>  $66+6+6+6/6 = 79$
>
>  $6!!/6+6 \times 6+6 \times 6 = 80$
>
>  $6!!+6 \times 6+.6-.6 \times 6 = 81$
>
>  $66+6+6+.\overline{6} \times 6 = 82$
>
>  $6!/6-6/6-6 \times 6 = 83$
>
>  $6+6+6 \times 6+6 \times 6 = 84$
>
>  $6!/6+6/6-6 \times 6 = 85$
>
>  $66 \times .\overline{6}+6+6 \times 6 = 86$
>
>  $.6+6 \times 6 \times .6 \times .\overline{6} \times 6 = 87$
>
>  $6!/6+6 \times .\overline{6}-6 \times 6 = 88$
>
>  $6!!+6+6 \times 6-6/6 = 89$
>
>  $6 \times 6 \times 6 \times .\overline{6} \times .\overline{6}-6 = 90$
>
>  $6!!+6+6/6+6 \times 6 = 91$
>
>  $6!! \times 6 \times .\overline{6} \times .\overline{6}-6 \times 6 = 92$
>
>  $6!!+6!!+6/6-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 93$
>
>  $6!!+6+6 \times 6+.\overline{6} \times 6 = 94$
>
>  $6!!+6!!+6-6-6/6 = 95$
>
>  $66+6+6 \times .\overline{6} \times 6 = 96$
>
>  $6!!+6!!+6+6/6-6 = 97$
>
>  $66+6 \times 6-.\overline{6} \times 6 = 98$
>
>  $6!/6+.6-6 \times .6 \times 6 = 99$
>
>  $6!!+6!!+6+6 \times .\overline{6}-6 = 100$

Comment: 80: 6!/(6*6) + 6*6/.6

Comment: $91=6!!+6*6+6+\frac{6}{6}$

Comment: $100=\frac{666-66}{6}$

Comment: How does 6!! = 48? Does 6!! mean something different from (6!)!?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes, it is a [double factorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) which is evaluated as $n \cdot (n-2) \dots$. $6!! = 6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 = 48$.

Answer (score 2):

Some numbers missing from eyl327's answer

> $80=6!/6-6\cdot6-.\bar6\cdot6$
>  $83=6!/6-6\cdot6-6/6$
>  $85=6!/6-6\cdot6+6/6$
>  $88=6!/6-6\cdot6+.\bar6\cdot6$
>  $96=6!/6-6-6-6-6$